# What's the best way to share configuration between different projects?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We've got 3-5 different projects. I don't wanna copy/paste each time some parts of configuration from one project to another (like adding common maven repository). What's the best way to share common configuration across different projects?

I've used `apply from: "http://path/to/common.build.gradle"` construction but our architector thinks that this is not the best solution because project build depends on external server that stores `common.build.gradle`. If you don't have connection to this server you can't build project. What do you think about it?

Comment: Have you thought about init script http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html?

Comment: Are you talking about different `builds`, or different `projects` of the same multi-project build?

Comment: I'm talking about different projects which doesn't have common parent project

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way to share configuration between builds is to code it up as a plugin class (i.e. a class implementing the `org.gradle.api.Plugin` interface), publish it as a Jar to a Maven or Ivy repository, and pull it in to consuming builds using a `buildscript` block. This will make sure that the plugin Jar gets cached like any other artifact dependency. How to go about this is explained in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: It's interesting. Do you have concrete examples (blog posts, articles) of using plugins to share common configuration settings?

Comment: I'm not aware of such resources, but a web search might turn up something. Performing common configuration is the very purpose of plugins. (Binary) plugins do exactly the same things as (reusable) build scripts, except that they are implemented as classes.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I found is to:

1. place the common file somewhere so it is url accessible. I chose artifactory OSS for publishing my common gradle files.
2. Use `apply from: 'http://acme.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/gradle/common.gradle'`

Note that Gradle caches the common.gradle so when you are offline you can run gradle with --ofline option (`gradle --ofline build`) and build still works if the file is in cache

There are [some gotchas](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508) to be aware of. Specifically you need to use the older plugin mechanism in common.gradle and use fully qualified classname (without any quotes arounbd it since it is a class reference). See gist below:

```groovy
buildscript {
    // Have to use old plugin mechanism if not in build.gradle
    // https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508/15
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
        classpath "pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.9.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
apply plugin: org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin
apply plugin: pl.allegro.tech.build.axion.release.ReleasePlugin
```

While this approach is simple and quick its downside is that your build process is not dependency managed and source controlled properly making it unpredictable and non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to write a custom gradle wrapper.   Forgive me for not giving an example but there is one here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

I've gone through it, and it seems to work well enough.  You set it up in its own project and publish the wrapper file beside your current wrapper, it has to be in a public area, then each project can just link to your new wrapper.

There are a tone of gochas as well, iirc the same syntax has to be used as in Farrukh's answer.  You can also mix this solution with each of the above solutions.  This solution is well off the beaten path, but it's a great solution when you have a large number of projects to be configured identically.